# como saber se a data é do tipo de data yyyy-mm-dd, dd/mm/yyyy etc?

Tags: php

a pergunta ainda fica mais difícil:

o campo `data_cadastro` está como **varchar**, tenho diversas tabelas e cada uma delas há um tipo diferente de data, como por exemplo: 
em uma tabela há:

- 2015-12-01;

na outra:

- 12/07/2015;

e em outra:

- 14-05-2015

etc...

há alguma maneira de se retornar se essa data é do tipo yyyy-mm-dd, dd-mm-yyyy, dd/mm/yyyy e vice-versa?

Comment: Assumindo que não existam anos com 2 dígitos, você poderia verificar se o 3º caractere é uma barra ou um traço. Se for, vc tem a data no formato dd/MM/yyyy ou dd-mm-yyyy. Acho que deve existir alguma outra forma, mas de cara, eu desconheço.

Comment: Existem vários exemplos de instruções SQL que permitem atualizar o valor das colunas para um dado formato (`str_to_date`). Quando finalizado, basta alterar a coluna para `Datetime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar expressões regulares:

```
<?php
function DateFormat($date){
   if (preg_match("/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/", $date))
      return 'YYYY-MM-DD';
   elseif (preg_match("/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/", $date))
      return 'DD/MM/YYYY';
   elseif (preg_match("/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/", $date))
      return 'DD-MM-YYYY';
   else return FALSE;
}

echo DateFormat('2015-12-01').PHP_EOL;
echo DateFormat('12/07/2015').PHP_EOL;
echo DateFormat('14-05-2015').PHP_EOL;

// Saída
// YYYY-MM-DD
// DD/MM/YYYY
// DD-MM-YYYY
```

Comment: Sugiro criar uma nova coluna no seu banco do tipo date e normaliza-lo utilizando um script. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Outra maneira utilizando expressões regulares:

```
$variations = array (
    '^([0-9]{4})/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{4}2$' => 'Y/m/d H:i:s',
    // Mais outras expressões regulares aqui
);

foreach ($dateFromDatabase as $date) {
    foreach ($variations as $regexp => $dateFormat) {
        if (preg_match ('|' . $regexp . '|', $date)) {
            $matches[$dateFromDatabase] = $dateFormat;
            break;
        }
    }
}
// $matches agora consiste em um array de datas => formato
```